# The screen remains black after suspending, xorg high on CPU

Tags: debian, xorg

Suspend used to work just fine on my laptop but since a recent update I am encountering an issue. After I wake the laptop from suspend, the screen doesn't come on. Everything else seems to turn on just fine, but no image on the screen. The laptop is fully awake, but there is just no image on the screen. In particular, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> does restart `X` which then works normally, and if I don't restart X I can use `top` or `ps` in a `tty` console and see that my graphical processes are still running.

One thing to note is that Xorg is *often* using an anormal level of CPU resources, even when the system is apparently running correctly (often at 50 or 100% CPU, e.g. over last session it used 1 hour CPU usage for 4 hours uptime...!)

```
>lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm
```

`journalctl` between a suspend and restart:

```
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse systemd-logind[792]: Lid closed.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse systemd-logind[792]: Suspending...
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse ModemManager[856]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.6778] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.6779] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.6783] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.6785] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse dbus-daemon[784]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=824 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon")
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse dbus-daemon[784]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8754] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8760] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::4433:344a:b093:aff7 on wlp2s0.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::4433:344a:b093:aff7.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8930] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8935] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8936] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8942] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8943] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.8943] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse dbus-daemon[1477]: [session uid=1001 pid=1477] Activating service name='org.xfce.Xfconf' requested by ':1.2706' (uid=1001 pid=296853 comm="xfdesktop")
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528270.9453] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 52:0E:6F:40:4D:0B (scanning)
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.107.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.107 on wlp2s0.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.107.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.107 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.107 on wlp2s0.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.107.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Oct 05 19:51:10 ulysse dbus-daemon[1477]: [session uid=1001 pid=1477] Successfully activated service 'org.xfce.Xfconf'
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528271.0409] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528271.0411] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528271.0424] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse systemd-logind[792]: Lid opened.
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696528271.2848] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to FC:77:74:4D:F8:91 (unmanage)
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse pkexec[300379]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1001)
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse pkexec[300379]: etienne: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/etienne] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness 7500]
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse systemd-sleep[300392]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Oct 05 19:51:11 ulysse kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.012 seconds
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Freezing user space processes
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: CPU1 is up
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: CPU2 is up
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: CPU3 is up
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: CPU4 is up
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: CPU5 is up
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: CPU6 is up
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: CPU7 is up
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: DMAR: [INTR-REMAP] Request device [f0:1f.0] fault index 0xc23 [fault reason 0x22] Present field in the IRTE entry is clear
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x411, Reinit
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:94:DDI A/PHY A] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:102:DDI B/PHY B] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:111:DDI C/PHY C] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0(NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0(NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: random: crng reseeded on system resumption
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: anacron.service - Run anacron jobs was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionACPower=true).
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd-sleep[300392]: System returned from sleep state.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: PM: suspend exit
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: Starting phpsessionclean.service - Clean php session files...
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd-sleep[300526]: /dev/sda:
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd-sleep[300526]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x80 (128)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd-sleep[300526]:  APM_level        = 128
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: Finished phpsessionclean.service - Clean php session files.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd-sleep[300589]: /dev/sda:
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd-sleep[300589]:  setting standby to 36 (3 minutes)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: Stopped target sleep.target - Sleep.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse systemd-logind[792]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531755.8634] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531755.8635] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse ModemManager[856]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531755.9404] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 05 20:49:15 ulysse kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: NIC Link is Down
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.1326] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.1826] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 96:51:39:92:91:9B (scanning)
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4190] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4201] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4797] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4798] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4811] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp2s0 created
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4819] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/48)
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4826] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4842] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:16 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531756.4863] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:18 ulysse ModemManager[856]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Oct 05 20:49:18 ulysse ModemManager[856]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6': not supported by any plugin
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=COUNTRY alpha2=FR
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9557] policy: auto-activating connection 'Cessna' (129f963c-5220-4c9e-a38a-9dc9e8fae811)
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9562] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Cessna' (129f963c-5220-4c9e-a38a-9dc9e8fae811)
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9564] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9566] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9783] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to FC:77:74:4D:F8:91 (preserve)
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9849] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9851] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Cessna' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9852] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9853] sup-iface[f8dd7a98deb844e4,29,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9857] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9857] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9865] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9867] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9869] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Cessna' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9869] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Cessna'
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9869] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9869] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9870] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Oct 05 20:49:19 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531759.9870] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: WPS-CANCEL
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0111] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0111] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 (SSID='Cessna' freq=2457 MHz)
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: authenticate with 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: send auth to 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 (try 1/3)
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0348] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0348] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 (SSID='Cessna' freq=2457 MHz)
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: authenticated
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: associate with 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 (try 1/3)
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0425] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0426] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not associated
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: Associated with 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: wlp2s0: associated
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0646] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.0647] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.1582] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.1584] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 50:d4:f7:22:67:e9 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse wpa_supplicant[851]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-48 noise=9999 txrate=1000
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2110] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2111] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Cessna"
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2112] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2117] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2135] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::4433:344a:b093:aff7.
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Registering new address record for fe80::4433:344a:b093:aff7 on wlp2s0.*.
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2267] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.107
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2307] policy: set 'Cessna' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.107.
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse avahi-daemon[781]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.107 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2493] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2538] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2541] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2545] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2558] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531760.2563] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Oct 05 20:49:20 ulysse kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: failed to re-enable notifications (-110)
Oct 05 20:49:22 ulysse NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1696531762.1481] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 05 20:49:25 ulysse rtkit-daemon[1061]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Oct 05 20:49:25 ulysse rtkit-daemon[1061]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Oct 05 20:49:25 ulysse rtkit-daemon[1061]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Oct 05 20:49:25 ulysse rtkit-daemon[1061]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
```

VGA driver:

```
>sudo lspci -s 00:02 -vnn
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 620 [1028:0815]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128, IOMMU group 0
    Memory at ee000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

**EDIT** Today I note these errors as the CPU usage of Xorg rockets up:

```
Oct 12 18:19:40 ulysse kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Sending link address failed with -5
Oct 12 18:19:58 ulysse kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Failed to get ACT after 3000ms, last status: 04
Oct 12 18:20:01 ulysse kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Failed to get ACT after 3000ms, last status: 04
Oct 12 18:20:31 ulysse kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
```

However... just after upgrading to bookworm, I hadn't yet added new `non-free-firmware` repo in my apt source list, so I didn't have firmware for the kernel, and bug started appear already. I installed firmware as one of the first steps to try solve it.

I'm running `xfce`, I have also tried changing desktop environment to `lxde` and had similar issues (but actually worse since switching consoles/restarting X was not possible)

Comment: I would try a previous kernel version, if available. If it works as expected then you should report a bug against the current kernel.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have now tried 6.1.0-8, 6.1.0-9 and linux-image-6.1.0-13-amd64 which all lead to the issue every few suspend. There's apparently no other version with debian bookworm.

Comment: Seems like i915 or kernel bug to me. You can try the official bug report guide, https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/wikis/How-to-file-i915-bugs

Comment: @MaxPlankton: I'll file a bug. I see that an issue already reported there mentions "with drmtip, issue is still observed" -- is "drmtip" some extra driver/whatever I can install on my system? Couldn't find explanations.

Comment: @MaxPlankton However... just after upgrading to bookworm, I hadn't yet added new `non-free-firmware` repo in my apt source list, so I didn't have firmware for the kernel, and bug started appear already. I installed firmware as one of the first steps to try solve it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to uninstall the xfce4-screensaver as suggested in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2072314#p2072314) thread.

This smells of a systemd bug imo.

Comment: I do not have xfce4-screensaver, as a matter of fact it's not part of bookworm distro. I don't think the other issues in the paged linked are relevant.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).